# jMeter: load file content on http request body

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to inject file content into the request body:

[image]

I'm using:

```
${__FileToString(${__eval(${bundle})},,)}
```

I've configured the `bundle` variable using the `directory listing plugin`:

[image]

When I perform the test, I'm getting:

[image]

Logs is getting me:

```
2021-12-28 16:33:53,853 WARN o.a.j.f.FileToString: Could not read open: /patient-bundle-0193.json
```

According to my configuration, `__FileToString` should read from `/home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/salut/mpi/jsons/bundles/extractions/10000/bundles` instead from `/`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tick `Use full path` so your `bundle` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) would contain the absolute location of the file.

[image]

Be informed that JMeter Variables along with their respective values can be visualized using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

You might also be interested in [Introducing the Directory Listing Config Plugin on JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) article